# How to convert unusual unicode string with number to integer in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers, int, python-unicode

I have some fairly hairy unicode strings with numbers in them that I'd like to test the value of.  Normally, I'd just use `str.isnumeric` to test for whether it could be converted via `int()` but I'm encountering cases where `isnumeric` returns `True` but `int()` raises an exception.

Here's an example program:

```
>>> s = '⒍'
>>> s.isnumeric()
True
>>> int(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '⒍'
```

Unicode is always full of surprises, so I'm happy to just be robust to this case and use a try/except block to catch unusual numbers.  However, I'd be happier if I could still convert them to integers.  Is there a consistent way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test if a string can be passed to `int`, use `str.isdecimal`. Both `str.isnumeric` and `str.isdigit` include decimal-like characters that aren't compatible with `int`.

And as @abarnert has mentioned in the comments, the most guaranteed way to test if a string can be passed to `int` is to simply do it in a `try` block.

On the other hand, '⒍' can be converted to an actual digit with the help of the `unicodedata` module, e.g.

```
print(unicodedata.digit('⒍'))
```

would output `6`.

Comment: This helps a lot, but any idea how to convert `⒍` to a integer or even a float?

Comment: Use `unicodedata`. `print(unicodedata.digit('⒍'))` outputs `6`.

Comment: @blhsing You should add that comment to the answer. But also, the _best_ way to test if a string can be passed to `int` is to just pass it to `int` in a `try:` block.

Comment: @abarnert Indeed. I've edited the answer as suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much luck you'll have, but unicodedata may handle some cases (python 3 code):

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', '⒍')
'6.'
```

Slightly better. As to testing, if you want an int you could just int() it and catch the exception.

Comment: This works, because `⒍` (`DIGIT SIX FULL STOP`) decomposes into `6` (`DIGIT SIX`) and `.` (`FULL STOP`), which can somewhat coincidentally be interpreted as a `float`, but it's not a general solution for all numeric/digit characters that aren't decimals.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to find out if a string can be converted to int is to just `try` it:

```
s = '⒍'
try:
    num = int(s)
except ValueError:
    # handle it
```

Sure, you can try to figure out the right way to test the string in advance, but why? If the rule you want is "whatever `int` accepts", just use `int`.

---

If you want to convert something that is a digit, but isn't a decimal, use the [`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.decimal) module:

```
s = '⒍'
num = unicodedata.digit(s) # 6
num = unicodedata.numeric(s) # 6.0
num = unicodedata.decimal(s) # ValueError: not a decimal
```

The [`DIGIT SIX FULL STOP`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/248d/index.htm) character's entry in the database has Digit and Numeric values, despite being a `Number, Other` rather than a `Number, Decimal Digit` (and therefore not being compatible with `int`).